# Multiple webapps with Tomcat 7 only results in "It works" page

Tags: tomcat

I'm not able to get the correct webapp requested for my domain.
I would like to have the webapp beside the ROOT webapp in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`.

Here's my `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>

      <Host name="example.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Alias>www.example.com</Alias>
        <Context docBase="example" path="" />
      </Host>

    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Everytime I request example.com I'm getting the "It works" page (ROOT webapp). When requesting example.com/example I'm getting the correct webapp.

Comment: That's the default behavior of Tomcat, so I'd say it works correctly. Do you mean you want to point the example.com to a different webapp instead of ROOT?

Comment: Yes. That's my intention. Shouldn't the default behavior be to use the defaultHost if no host can be resolved? But I configured my example.com host.

Comment: I'd say the defaultHost doesn't have anything to do with the webapps, it just configures the host where the Tomcat server is running. A way to achieve what you want is well described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application

Comment: I already tried point 2 but without success

Comment: What's the content of your `ROOT.xml` file?

Comment: There's no `/etc/tomcat7/ROOT.xml`

Comment: According to the second way, you should place a `ROOT.xml` file in your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/` directory with the content described. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thats point 3, not 2.